# How to send data from jquery to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
     $.getJSON('chartState',{
                    stateCode : $(this).val(),
                        ajax : 'true'
                },
                function(data) {
                    alert("state data"+data);
                });
</script>
```

I have the value in data and want to show in `javascript` given below.
The fields **data** is given want to push my state data there.

```
   <script>
        var salesChartData = {
            datasets: [{
                    data: ["here i want my data"]
                }]
        };
   </script>
```

Both are written in diffrent script

Comment: `salesChartData.datasets[0].label`, `salesChartData.datasets[0].fillColor` and so on. obviously you can iterate over the key/value pairs

Comment: Isn't jQuery written in JavaScript?

Comment: I am getting data from database in jquery  function ,so how can i get this value in javascript

Comment: I am getting every thing fine,only the problem is i can not show my data getting from database ,in daset you can see i have mention "here i want my data" in that place i want my database data.@caramba

Comment: both are written in diffrent script @Harun Yilmaz

Answer (score 1):

`datasets` is an array with an object on index 0. So to define or redeclare the `data` property in there the syntax is

```
salesChartData.datasets[0].data = data;
```

Use it in your callback function:

```
function(data) {
   salesChartData.datasets[0].data = data;
});
```

Comment: thank u for your answer,but how can i get my jquery data here

Comment: I am getting every thing fine,only the problem is i can not show my data getting from database ,in dataset you can see i have mention "here i want my data" in that place i want my database data

Comment: Do you need the key/value pairs from your received `data` to append to `datasets` also as key/value paired? So no `data` attribute?

Comment: i am getting my data in this format 10,45,21,10,5,45 and exact data i want to push there

Comment: Is `10,45,21,10,5,45` a string or an array?

Comment: its an array @kmgt

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, is this what you need?

```
var salesChartData = {
  datasets: [
    {
      data :  {}
    }
  ]
};


$.getJSON('chartState',{
  stateCode : $(this).val(),
  ajax : 'true'
},
function(data) {
  salesChartData.datasets[0].data = data;
});
```

Just set the data after receiving it

Comment: how it will interact with the js without using any id or class,both are written in different script

Comment: The "both are written in different script" part wasn't in the question when i sent you my answer. 

In any case, javascript vars are global, so you just need to make sure that the script that creates the var "salesChartData" is called/included/defined before the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to show the `ajax` result in a variable `salesChartData`, you can try this 
`salesChartData.datasets[0].data[0] = "new data"`

`salesChartData` is a JSON object with key `datasets` contains an array of JSON objects.

So if `salesChartData` is declared globally, then you can replace in the success of the `ajax`

Here below, it done using [web storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). This is used to access from different file.

```
// File 1
var salesChartData = {
    datasets: [{
        data: ["here i want my data"]
    }]
};
localStorage.setItem("salesChart", JSON.stringify(salesChartData));

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

// File 2

var salesChartData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("salesChart"));

// ajax call
$.getJSON('chartState', {
        stateCode: $(this).val(),
        ajax: 'true'
    },
    function (data) {
        alert("state data" + data);
        salesChartData.datasets[0].data[0] = data // "new data"
    });
```

Hope this will work.

Thank You

Comment: how it will interact with the js without using any id or class,both are written in different script

Comment: @Zubair: For accing from different files, you need to add the value in [web storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: everywhere i got that they sending value in jsp's div by class or by id but in my case i am not using any jsp

Comment: @Zubair: Can you please elaborate. I didn't get you much.

Comment: @Zubair: You can use by storing a hidden input text also.

Comment: Firstly thanks alot that you are being nice to me,As you see in my code i have jquery where i am getting data from controller,after that i am making a sales chart where i have to show that value using javascript,

Comment: @Zubair: You need to fetch the data from the controller using jquery and update the data set for the chart. And thus you need to redraw the sales chart in the success of the ajax call. 
Please upvote the comment, answer and accept the answer if it is useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I have done with my self

```
$.getJSON('chartState',{
    stateCode : $(this).val(),
        ajax : 'true'
},
function(data) {
    var chr=data;
      var a=chr[0];var b=chr[1];var c=chr[2];var d=chr[3];
      var e=chr[4];var f=chr[5];var g=chr[6];
```

After that I have sended one by one data

```
var salesChartData = {
  datasets: [   
    {

      data                :  [g,f,e,d,c,b,a]
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mention that both parts of the script are in different  tags you can solve the problem with a global, this is not recommended. The better solution would be to refactor the structure and not have multiple script tags. But if you have no control over this then you should do something like this:

```
<script>
     // No var used to make it global
     chart_state_data = false;
     $.getJSON('chartState',{
                    stateCode : $(this).val(),
                        ajax : 'true'
                },
                function(data) {
                    // the data is set to this variable on callback
                    chart_state_data = data
                });
</script>
```

And:

```
  <script>
        // chart_state_data contains data retrieved from ajax call or false
        var salesChartData = {
            datasets: [{
                    data: chart_state_data
                }]
        };
   </script>
```